# How to get the SharePoint Folder Details based on it's GUID

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I am migrating SharePoint application from SharePoint to SharePoint CSOM. The SharePoint server is 2013 in house server. Previously I have a direct function in SharePoint to get the Folder Details by it's GUID.

Direct Function
Web.GetFolder(GUID).

Now as I am migrating the SharePoint code to SharePoint CSOM I didn't find any direct method to get the folder details based on the GUID. I am using the reference of SharePointPnPCore2013 for migrating it to SharePoint CSOM. Can you help me with any method reference to get the folder details based on GUID.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for your reference(SharePoint CSOM).

```
var specialFolder = context.Web.GetFolderById( new Guid("471f031a-4b7d-4a18-bb63-310923e5c285"));
                context.Load(specialFolder);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. 

No Offense but the GetFolderById won't work with SharePoint 2013 CSOM. It will work with SharePoint Online. There is a bit difference between those both. The SharePoint 2013 server is in house and SharePoint online is completely cloud. So the GetFolderById will work with SharePoint Online but not with SharePoint 2013 CSOM. 
The above comments are given based on my understanding. If I miss anything kindly let me know.
Thanks